# Injecting gatsby-image into html created from markdown using ReactDOMServer.renderToString

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image, react-dom-server

[Minimum Reproducible Example on Github](https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/gatsby-image-is-black)

---

I'm trying to inject some images into my pages created from markdown. I'm trying to do this using ReactDomServer.renderToString()

```
const componentCreatedFromMarkdown = ({data}) => {
...    
    useEffect(() => {
        const injectDivs = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('injectDivs'))
        injectDivs.forEach((aDiv) => {
            aDiv.innerHTML = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Img fluid={data.allFile.edges[0].node.childImageSharp.fluid} />)
        }
    })
...
}
```

The img is showing as a black box, if I right click the image I can open it in a new tab, which shows the image as it is supposed to be.

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How I understand the problem

- The image html is correctly inserted into the page
- `gatsby-image` loads the lowest quality image and applies some inline
  styles. All that information is present in the html)  This is done to
  enable the blur-up effect on the image for a better UX.
- The client side code that would load a higher resolution image and remove the  inline styles is never applied.

#### Useful diagnostic information

- The function inside `useEffect` does not get run on the server-side, but rather on the client after the component has mounted. It's possible to verify this by adding a `console.log` statement inside the effect and seeing that it is logged on the browser's console.

#### Source of the problem

- `ReactDOMServer.renderToString()` only builds the HTML that's required by a component, it then requires the component to be [hydrated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate).

#### Direct fix

- You can use `ReactDOM.render` to put the image on the page, given that the effect will execute client side. I have a PR showing that [here](https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/gatsby-image-is-black/pull/1).

#### Recommended approach

- You could instead import the image inside the mdx component and directly render it there. Your gatsby config can already support this  In `content/blog/hello-world/index.mdx`, you can replace the `injectImage` div with this `![A salty egg, yummm](./salty_egg.jpg)` (where the text inside the `[]` is the alt text)
- This documentation might be helpful

  - https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/working-with-images-in-markdown/
  - https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-remark-images/

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm injecting it because it's a random image that changes every time you load the page

Comment: Okay, hopefully the direct fix helps then! 

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem before with my first Gatsby project.
The problem similar to this [chat](https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js/general/black-stuff-around-webp-images%7E3a0c4f1b-aa4d-4ae9-a947-3d0750162d48) and the error image issue [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgIrE.jpg).

If you replace `GatsbyImageSharpFixed_withWebp_tracedSVG` like they talked in spectrum chat above, or this is my current code for example, basically is related to `WebP` new image format.

```
export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allImageSharp {
      edges {
        node {
          fluid(maxWidth: 110) {
            aspectRatio
            originalName
            sizes
            src
            srcSet
            srcWebp
            tracedSVG
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: One notable link: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/14497

Comment: This just creates a weird black and gray outline

Comment: Could you provide any screenshot or code, because your current code seems no problem with me.

Comment: I posted a [Minimum Reproducible example on Github](https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/gatsby-image-is-black)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be in the useEffect

const componentCreatedFromMarkdown = ({data}) => {

```
...    
    useEffect(() => {
        const injectDivs = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('injectDivs'))
        injectDivs.forEach((aDiv) => {
            aDiv.innerHTML = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<MyComponent args={myArgs} />)
        }
    },[])
...
}
```

I think you should try to add useEffect(()=>{},[]), the second argument to refresh the image only when the component is mounted, without this the image will be refreshed each time.

Comment: I posted a [Minimum Reproducible example on Github](https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/gatsby-image-is-black). You're solution didn't fix it unfortunately.